# Benny, Denny, Kenny and Lenny: Who lies and who tells the truth?

Tags: logical-deduction, liars

**To allow new users to solve this puzzle and earn reputation points, I encourage all users whose reputation is 200 or more to not post an answer until 48 hours after this question is posted. Thank you!**

---

Each of Benny, Denny, Kenny and Lenny either always lies or always tells the truth.

- Benny claims that Denny is a liar.
- Lenny claims that Benny is a liar.
- Kenny claims that both Benny and Denny are liars.
- Kenny also claims that Lenny is a liar.

Which of them always lies and which of them always tells the truth?

---

<sub>This puzzle came from a Leningrad Mathematical Olympiad.</sub>

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok, so this is the key understanding that made this make sense.

> Kenny says that both of Benny and Denny are liars. Because of Benny's statement that Denny is a liar, Benny and Denny will always have opposite truth values. If Benny is True then Denny is False and vise versa.

Which means

> Kenny must be a liar. Which means he is lying when he says that Lenny is a liar. Thus Lenny is telling the truth when he says that Benny is a liar.

Thus the final outcome is

> Lenny and Denny are the two truth tellers, and Kenny and Benny are the two liars.

Comment: Welcome to PSE (Puzzling Stack Exchange)!